# Uncaught Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $cordovaPushV5Provider <- $cordovaPushV5

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I am working with cordovaPushV5 plugin to be able to implement push notifications on my app.

I am doing exactly as in this tutorial: https://github.com/yafraorg/yafra/wiki/Blog-Ionic-PushV5

When I run the app on my browser, I get the above error in console.

I installed the plugin correctly and included the necessary lines of code in my App.js file as shown below.

Could someone help me know where I am going wrong?

```js
/****ENABLE RECEIVING OF PUSH NOTIFICATIONS****/
/*
 * start within Platform ready
 */
$ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    // register push notification and get local push token
    localStorage.myPush = ''; // I use a localStorage variable to persist the token
    $cordovaPushV5.initialize(  // important to initialize with the multidevice structure !!
        {
            android: {
                senderID: "704649974960"
            },
            ios: {
                alert: 'true',
                badge: true,
                sound: 'false',
                clearBadge: true
            },
            windows: {}
        }
    ).then(function (result) {
        $cordovaPushV5.onNotification();
        $cordovaPushV5.onError();
        $cordovaPushV5.register().then(function (resultreg) {
            localStorage.myPush = resultreg;
            // SEND THE TOKEN TO THE SERVER, best associated with your device id and user
        }, function (err) {
            // handle error
        });
    });
});

/*
 * Push notification events
 */
$rootScope.$on('$cordovaPushV5:notificationReceived', function(event, data) {  // use two variables here, event and data !!!
    if (data.additionalData.foreground === false) {
        // do something if the app is in foreground while receiving to push - handle in app push handling
        
    } else {
       // handle push messages while app is in background or not started
    }
    if (Device.isOniOS()) {
        if (data.additionalData.badge) {
            $cordovaPushV5.setBadgeNumber(NewNumber).then(function (result) {
                // OK
            }, function (err) {
                // handle error
            });
        }
    }

    $cordovaPushV5.finish().then(function (result) {
        // OK finished - works only with the dev-next version of pushV5.js in ngCordova as of February 8, 2016
    }, function (err) {
        // handle error
    });
});

$rootScope.$on('$cordovaPushV5:errorOccurred', function(event, error) {
    // handle error
});
/****END ENABLE RECEIVING OF PUSH NOTIFICATIONS****/
```

Comment: Did you inject `$cordovaPushV5` in your controller? Did you add `ngCordova.plugins.push_v5` module as a dependency to your app?

Comment: @RaviTeja I injected itand the code is inside:

`.run(function ($rootScope,$cordovaPushV5,$ionicPlatform, $state, AuthService, AUTH_EVENTS) {   
//Code here
}`

I have not added the dependency, but I installed ngCordova. How do I add it please?

Answer (score 1):

Sailing in the same boat. Saw a couple of things missing from my `index.html` file. I am using `ionic` project.

```
<!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
<script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
<script src="lib/ionic-service-core/ionic-core.js"></script>
<script src="lib/ionic-service-push/ionic-push.js"></script>

<!-- ngCordova -->
<script src="lib/cordova/ng-cordova.min.js"></script>

<!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
<script src="cordova.js"></script>
<script src="lib/ngCordova/dist/ng-cordova.min.js">
```

If you see the there are two folders for `ng-cordova.min.js` file. The `lib/ngCordova/dist/ng-cordova.min.js` has the `$cordovaPushV5` definition.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks. I also solved the error by following what Ravi said above.